# displaying a color instead of none

Tags: html, css

I would like to ask if on how do I change the background of the page.
So instead of using `display: none;` I want to change the background to blue. But every time that I use `background-color: blue;` the texts are there it's just the page is colored as blue. Is there a way to change the background-color without implementing it in the body instead implement it in the direct child of the body eg. div/navbar etc?

Comment: Please edit your question and include minimum code example so we can see *exactly* what you mean, then we can help you.

Comment: So are you wanting to change the background color to blue while trying to mimic `display: none`? If so you would just make the text have `color: transparent`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    this is the body
    <div id="div1">This is div 1</div>
    <div id="div2">this is div 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```